# aws programmatic access need to update on daily basis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have several users for AWS for different accounts. I work with one of them on daily basis. I am not sure why this changed, maybe it was that I changed it from been the default, the other option is that there was an access policy update. Everyday I have to manually update the `~/.aws/credentials` fields `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key`, and the `aws_session_token` values.
Is there a way to avoid this manual process?

Comment: It sounds like you've set up temporary credentials and not the long lived credentials.  Temporary credentials are short lived intentionally.  Do you have to have the temporary type of credentials?

Comment: @stdunbar thank you for your comment, I was able to solve it. I realized that there are two types of credentials. I went to IAM and I saw that the credential I have was long term credential (everyday I was setting up short lived credentials). I setup that credential and everything is working as before. Thanks!

Comment: If you continue to use persistent IAM User credentials then be aware of various [security best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) including [rotating credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#rotate-credentials).